# Is it possible to reenter a while loop after it has been broken out of?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So when I set a "break;" statement at the end of a while loop, or when it's condition is set to false, is there any way to jump back to the top of the loop and go through it once again?

I know of the "continue;" statement. It jumps back to the top of the while loop, but only when it is declared inside of that loop.

Is there some way of achieving the same effect after exiting the loop completely?

```
while(true) {
    //code
    break;
}

int i=1;

if(i=1) {
    //command to go back into the while loop
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to nest the loop in another loop. What is the condition on which you want to run the loop again?

Comment: The condition the loop is running on is just a boolean set to true. Nesting it inside another loop might even help my problem.. I'll try it

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve with a sample of code. Even if it is pseudo code it would help. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: No, it's not possible, not in a procedural language.

Comment: perhaps put your loop in a method and do not use variables local to the loop so they remain the same when you break the loop then you can call the method(loop) again is best I can think of

Comment: You could wrap the entire loop in *another* loop. Not sure if that's what you're asking though.

Comment: Hey Pearl, sounds like a good idea. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you could solve by splitting your code into methods and reusing them?

```java
void executeLoop() {
    while(true) {
        //code
        break;
    }
}

void doStuff() {
    executeLoop();
    int i=1;

    if(i==1) { // Added a = symbol here to compare instead of assigning
        executeLoop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

You can use goto() label and add a label at the top of the loop.

label:
While loop
goto label;

Comment: `goto` may be reserved in Java, but it doesn't actually mean anything